# Common practice / method for encoding and unnecoding data which scales from CSV to MySQL table to Web

Tags: php, mysql, csv, character-encoding

I have a simple shopping cart web site that uses a MySQL database to store the products. There are THOUSANDS of products, and as a result these items can be managed from both a web based interface as WELL as by generating a TSV file, downloading, editing and re-uploading which then parses the now changed CSV file, making the correct changes as it goes.

Now you can imagine the nightmares I have been facing in terms of character encoding etc. My question is this: Is there a common practice, efficient way to encode - store - retrieve - unencode data for use accross CSV, MySQL and Web platform?

I am finding that the admins may enter a certain description in the CSV which is simply copied and pasted from somewhere. That description may contain special characters such as copyright and trademark symbols, and even 'power to' and 'squared' math characters.

What would be the best method to ensure that these special characters are kept intact in the database and are also able to be displayed in the web site with no worries, and when downloaded as a TSV file they are once again encoded back to a format the Excel(R) will display as the special character and not some character code.

As always, any feedback / guidance is always appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use UTF-8 in every step of the process (with an UTF-8 BOM when generating the CSV so Windows gets it) and you won't have any problems.

Give your html files and/or server headers an UTF-8 encoding and your tables an UTF-8 encoding and everything should work without a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I had a feeling that perhaps UTF8 was the way to go. So if all my pages have a UTF-8 header, will I NOT need to encode the CSV data to htmlentities() when adding to the database? I assume if my page header has UTF-8 character set then there will be no need to encode to html characters?

Comment: @webfac: Assuming the characters you're using are within the UTF8 character set, you won't need `htmlentities()`. Encoding is only needed if the characters are not supported by your character set. So to be safe you can still use `htmlentities()` but call it with charset `UTF-8` like this: `htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: So when I insert the data into the tables I use the htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') and then how would I then get those characters BACK to UTF-8 for reading into Excel? Or is that where htmlentities_decode() comes into play?

Comment: The `htmlentities()` is only for displaying the data in the html. For the rest it's not needed. Also, it only changes something if you try to encode a character that's outside of the UTF-8 character range. Basically... if you simply use UTF-8 everywhere you probably won't have any problems. Even without `htmlentities()`